# ReactJS unable to send POST request due to CORS options preflight

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, graphql

Whenever I send a `POST` request to the server, `OPTIONS` is **ALWAYS** being returned.

I have a very simple login app using `React` and `Apollo`. When I submit the form, a `mutation` should be sent to the server using **POST** request but **OPTIONS** always intercepts.

As you can see here (**using chrome**):
[image]

But when I am using **Firefox**, after the `OPTIONS`, **POST** is requested next as you can see here:

[image]

I know I cannot disable preflight OPTIONS because as what I had researched, using `Content-Type: application/json` / `bodyParser.json()`  triggers the preflight.

But I need `Content-Type: application/json` in order for `graphql` to work. But is there any possible way to just **POST** the request and ignore the **OPTIONS**?
 I need the `this.props.data` returned by POST request 
[image]

so I can store the token in the localStorage in the client browser...

**My problems were:**

- POST request never happen because of OPTIONS (chrome)
- I cannot access `this.props.data` in the React component because
  `OPTIONS` is always returned **FIRST** before the actual **POST**(in Firefox)

I just want to get the `data` from the POST request

Is this an issue to the cors? Can someone enlighten me what I am doing wrong? Thank you very much in advanced.

PS:
I have tried this link: https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql/issues/14 but still, I cannot fix this issue...

**Here is my server:**

```
const express = require('express')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
// Grahql
const expressGraphQL = require('express-graphql')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const cors = require('cors')
const chalk = require('chalk')

const model = require('./db/models')
const schema = require('./schema/schema')

const app = express()
app.use(cors())
app.options('*', cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(morgan('dev'))

// secret key
const SECRET = 'eggieandsausage'

// this method checks token authenticity from
// user attempting to login
const verifyTokenAuthenticity = async (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.headers['authentication']
    try {
        // verify token from headers
        const { user } = await jwt.verify(token, SECRET)
        // store user in req
        req.user = user
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
    // proceed
    next()
}

// Graphql
//app.use(verifyTokenAuthenticity)

app.use('/graphql', expressGraphQL(req => ({
    schema,
    graphiql: true,
    // this context is accessible within resolve()
    context: {
        model,
        SECRET,
        user: req.user
    }
})))


// Initial Route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(chalk.green(`MAGIC STARTS AT PORT ${PORT}`)))
```

**Here is My Mutation:**

```
const graphql = require('graphql')
const {
    GraphQLObjectType,
    GraphQLString,
    GraphQLNonNull
} = graphql
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')



const UserType = require('./types/user_type')

const mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Mutation',
    fields: {
        signup: {
            type: UserType,
            args: { 
                email: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
                password: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) }
            },
            resolve(parentValue, { email, password }, { model }) {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    model.User.create({
                        email,
                        password
                    })
                    .then(user => {
                        if (!user)
                            return reject('Sorry. something went wrong')
                        resolve(user)
                    })
                    .catch(error => reject(error))
                })
            }
        },
        signin: {
            type: UserType,
            args: {
                email: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
                password: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) }
            },
            // params: parentValue, args, context
            resolve(parentValue, { email, password }, { model, SECRET }) {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    model.User.find({ where: { email } })
                        .then(user => {
                            if (!user)
                                return reject('Invalid Credentials')
                            if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password))
                                return reject('Invalid Credentials')

                            const token = jwt.sign({ user: { id: user.id, email: user.email } }, SECRET, { expiresIn: '1yr' })
                            user.token = token  // add token property to user object which will be resolved

                            resolve(user)

                        })
                        .catch(error => reject(error))
                })

            }
        }
    }
})

module.exports = mutation
```

**And this is the login page**

```
import React from 'react'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo'
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { email: 'edrren@gmail.com', password: 'password' }
    }
    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        const { email, password } = this.state
        console.log({ email, password })
        this.props.mutate({
            variables: { email, password }
        }).then(() => console.log(this.props.data))
        .catch(() => console.log("error"))
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="text" onChange={(e) => this.setState({ email: e.target.value})} value={this.state.email} />
                <br/>
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" onChange={(e) => this.setState({ password: e.target.value})} value={this.state.password} />
                <button type="submit" >Login</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
const mutation = gql`
    mutation SignIn($email: String!, $password: String!){
      signin(email: $email, password: $password) {
        token
      }
    }
`;
export default graphql(mutation)(App)
```

**My provider:**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import ApolloClient, { createNetworkInterface } from 'apollo-client'
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import App from './App'
import Header from './components/Header'
import Profile from './components/Profile'
const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface({
  uri: 'http://localhost:8080/graphql'
});
const client = new ApolloClient({
    networkInterface,
    dataIdFromObject: o => o.id
})
const Root = () => {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Router>
          <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
          <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </ApolloProvider>
  )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Root />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: what is the URL of your UI?

Comment: @Hriday It is http://localhost:3000

Comment: If you are using create-react-app then you can proxy your request. for example `"proxy": {
    "/graphql": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8080"
    }
  }`

Comment: May I know where to put it? Yes I am using cra

Comment: In package.json, outermost level i.e. in main object

Comment: I will try i Sir

Comment: It is still not working sir

Comment: For your reference [https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-create-react-app-work-with-a-node-backend-api-7c5c48acb1b0](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-create-react-app-work-with-a-node-backend-api-7c5c48acb1b0).  This blog is for node js, but should work for all backend API

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173642/discussion-between-hriday-modi-and-welp).

Comment: i sent something in chat sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use proxy in create-react-app project.

Add following proxy in `package.json` main object:

```
"/graphql": {
  "target": "http://localhost:8080/",
  "changeOrigin": true
}
```

It basically proxy's your request from "http://localhost:3000/graphql" to "http://localhost:8080/graphql".

Also change your code to use relative api url. So now it would be:

```
 uri: '/graphql'
```

This will make an api call to your local url and node server will proxy it to mentioned target. Hence no cross origin involved here.